# Javascript Closures: Understanding difference between let and var with an example

Tags: javascript, jquery

Although i understand that `let` allows you to declare variables that are limited in scope to the block, I encountered a strange difference between `let` and `var` while using it with javascript closures. Here is my example:

**With `let`:**

```js
function buildFunction() {

  var arr = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let j = i;  //Using let to assign j
    arr.push(
      function(){
        console.log(j);
      }
    )
  }
   return arr;
}

var fs = buildFunction();
fs[0]();
fs[1]();
fs[2]();
```

The above code snippet outputs:

```
0
1
2
```

**With `var`:**

```js
function buildFunction() {

  var arr = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var j = i;  //Using var to assign j
    arr.push(
      function(){
        console.log(j);
      }
    )
  }
   return arr;
}

var fs = buildFunction();
fs[0]();
fs[1]();
fs[2]();
```

The above code snippet outputs the following:

```
2
2
2
```

My question is:

1. If U am using `var` inside a block and assigning it a value during execution, shouldn't it work exactly like let and store different copies of j in memory ?
2. Does javascript handle `let` and `var` differently within a closure ?

Any clarifications on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @oen44: No this is not a duplicate. Please read the question carefully

Comment: I think it answers "*if i am using var inside a block, shouldn't it work exactly like let?*" perfectly fine. The answer to the second question (*No*) becomes irrelevant then.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`var` scopes to the function; `let` scopes to a block of code.

In your example `j` is scoped to the function `buildFunction()` when you use var. This means your using the 'same' `j` in every function. When your for loop runs j is set to 0, then 1, then 2. When you then run the console logs your referencing the j that was set to 2, so you get `2 2 2`.

When you use `let`, you scope `j` to that iteration of the for loop. This means every iteration has a 'different' `j`, and the console logs print what you expect them to print.

If you were using ES5 and needed to use var, you could replicate the let effect (have it print `0 1 2`), by wrapping your original anonymous function with a self-executing function and passed `j` in as an argument. This would create a new scope for `j` in the self-executing function whose value is the value of j in the current iteration.

```js
function buildFunction() {

  var arr = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var j = i;  //Using var to assign j
    arr.push(
      //self executing function
      (function(j) { //j here is scoped to the self executing function and has the value of j when it was called in the loop. Any changes to j here will not affect the j scope outside this function, and any changes to j outside this function will not affect the j scoped inside this function.
        //original function
        return function() {
          console.log(j);
        }
      })(j) //call with the value of j in this iteration
    )
  }

  return arr;
}

var fs = buildFunction();
fs[0]();
fs[1]();
fs[2]();
```

Comment: If every iteration has a different j, how does "for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) { j++; console.log(j); }" print "1 3 5" and not "1 2 3 4 5" ?